# Making changes to old commit

Tags: git, svn

Assume that I have 4 branches: part1, part2, part3 and master. Part 1 has 1 commit (first commit), part 2 has 2 commits (first commit, second commit) and part 3 has 3 commits (first, second and third). I want to make some changes to the first commit in part1 and also reflect those changes in other commits of other branches. What is the fastest way to do that?

Comment: Please review the answers given.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't think of any silver bullet which would let you make a change to the first commit in the `part1` branch and have it automatically update the first commit in the other 3 branches.  The main reason for this is that the first commit is actually different in all 4 of your branches.  You can convince yourself of this by checking the SHA-1 hash of the first commit in these branches.

That being said, if you want to rewrite the history of the first commit, then you can do an interactive rebase.  Here is an example of how to do this for the `part3` branch:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

This should prompt you with a screen which looks like the following:

```
pick dkj398u third commit message
pick l2mnx73 second commit message
edit 36e74bn first commit message
```

Note carefully that I have changed the action on the first commit to `edit`.  When you save this file and leave the editor, Git will run the rebase but will stop at the first commit.  This will give you a chance to make the changes you want.  After this, you can commit these changes and continue the rebase via:

```
git rebase --continue
```

You can repeat this procedure for the remaining branches.  For future reference, note that if the first commit were the most recent one for *all* the branches, then you could have used `git commit --amend` on all of them to modify the commit with resorting to a rebase.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **git rebase**, for example, if you want to modify back to commit **baa643cd**, run

```
$ git rebase --interactive baa643cd
```

In the default editor, modify 'pick' to 'edit' in the line whose commit you want to modify. Make your changes and then commit them with the same message you had before:

```
$ git commit --all --amend --no-edit
```

to modify the commit, and after that

```
$ git rebase --continue
```

to return back to the previous head commit.